# Multivariable Linear Equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a method to determine if a such an equation has a solution? For example, $2x_1+2x_2+8x_3+3x_4+3x_5=0$ has one possible solution $[-2,-2,1,-1,1]$

Solution is not required.

Comment: This equation has a pentuple infinity of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This equation has a pentuple infinity of solutions ! You may select any four numbers and get the fifth from the equation.

If you have a problem with N unknowns (here : x1, x2, x3, x4, x5), in order to find their values (if they exist), you must have N equations. If you have only M equations (M < N), still admitting that solutions exist, you could express M solutions as functions of (N-M) variables.

Does this clarify your question ?

Comment: I don't need a solution, what I meant was is there any way to tell if such an equation has no solution?

Comment: I think that my answer shoed that there is an infinite number of solutions or none. It depends how you want to look at this statement. Cheers.

Comment: So there's no way of knowing if a solution exists without the system of linear equations?